# Construir un algoritmo que permita ingresar un grupo de personas en una matriz por medio de subprocesos

Tags: pseint

Construir un algoritmo que permita ingresar un grupo de personas, `nombre`, `run` y `sexo` en una matriz por medio de sub procesos

```
Proceso Principal

    Dimension personas[100,3];
    definir nombre, run, sexo Como Caracter;
    definir continuar Como Logico;
    definir respuesta Como Caracter;
    definir cuentapersonas como entero;
    continuar = verdadero;

    Mientras continuar=verdadero hacer
        Escribir "Ingrese el Run : ";
        leer run;
        //validar run o rechazar; primera subrutina

        Escribir "Ingrese Nombre: ";
        leer nombre;

        Escribir "Ingrese sexo : [F/M]"
        //validar solo F o M

        // buscar que no esté repetido; segunda subrutina
        Escribir "Continua? [S/N]";
        //validar s y n.
        si respuesta= "S" y cuentapersonas<=100 Entonces
            continuar = verdadero;
        sino 
            continuar = falso;
        FinSi
    FinMientras

    //mostrar el resultado. tercera subrutina.

FinProceso
```

Comment: Eso es lo que llevo hasta ahora pero no se me ocurre como validar el run en el subproceso.

Comment: 1. El run debe ser validado o informar el error y rechazar a esa persona.
2. Las personas no pueden repetirse dentro de la matriz.
3. Mostrar el listado de las personas, primero mostrar a las personas de sexo femenino y luego a las de sexo masculino.

Comment: _El run debe ser validado_ ¿Qué es el run? ¿Cuáles son las reglas de validación que tiene que pasar para ser válido?

Answer (score 1):

### Funciones/Subprocesos

```
Funcion variable_de_retorno <- nombre_de_la_funcion ( argumento_1, argumento_2, ... )
    // codigo..
FinFuncion
```

Comienza con la palabra clave `Funcion` (alternativamente puede utilizar `SubProceso` o `SubAlgoritmo`, son sinónimos) seguida de la variable de retorno, el signo de asignación, el nombre del subproceso, y finalmente, la lista de argumentos entre paréntesis. Existen variantes para esta estructura.

- Si la función **no retorna** ningún valor, pueden omitirse la variable de
  retorno y el signo de asignación. Es decir, se puede colocar
  directamente el nombre y los argumentos a continuación de la palabra
  clave Funcion.
- Si el subproceso **no recibe** ningún valor pueden colocarse los
  paréntesis vacíos u omitirse, finalizando la primer línea con el
  nombre del subproceso.

Además, opcionalmente pueden agregarse las palabras claves `Por Valor` o `Por Referencia` para indicar el tipo de pasaje en cada argumento. Si no se indica, los arreglos se pasan por referencia, las demás expresiones por valor.

- El **pasaje por referencia** implica que si la función modifica el
  argumento, se modificará en realidad la variable que se utilizó en la
  llamada.
- El **pasaje por valor** implica que la función opera con una copia de
  la variable (o el resultado de la expresión) que se utilizó en la
  llamada, por lo que las modificaciones que aplique la función no se
  verán reflejadas fuera de la misma.

Para **invocar** a la función se debe utilizar su nombre y entre paréntesis los parámetros.

```
// Funcion que no recibe argumentos ni devuelve nada
Funcion Saludar
    Escribir "Hola mundo!"
FinFuncion

// Funcion que recibe el argumento nombre, y devuelve el saludo
Funcion respuesta <- SaludarA(nombre) 
    respuesta <- "Hola " + nombre
FinFuncion

// Proceso principal, que invoca a las funciones antes declaradas
Algoritmo PruebaFunciones

    // Llamada a la funcion Saludar
    // Como no recibe argumentos pueden omitirse los paréntesis vacios
    Saludar

    // Llamada a la función SaludarA()
    Escribir "Ingrese el nombre de la persona:"
    Leer nombrePersona
    Escribir SaludarA(nombre)

FinAlgoritmo
```

> La documentación sobre el pseudocódigo se encuentra en la opción `Ayuda > Indice` de la barra de navegación o mediante el atajo de teclado `F1`.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte

Comment: De nada, te invito a que intentes resolver el problema por ti mismo y en el caso de ser necesario que actualices la pregunta original con el nuevo código.